# How can I play a video in the earpiece with VLC?

Tags: audio, video, vlc, earpiece

By default, videos play in speaker with VLC. How can I play a video in the earpiece with VLC?

I don't see any option:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

This answer may not be 100% because you asked about VLC, however [Stealth Audio Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer&hl=en) is able to play audios (& audio from videos)  via the earpiece.

> Usually, there are two ways of playing music on Android device. You can either use your headphones or a speaker. But how about a third option?
>
> The purpose of this app is to enable the users to listen to something when they do not have earphones and they don't want to use speakers.

> This is useful not just for usual audio files, but also for podcasts, and comes in handy for when you forgot to bring headphones and do not want to disturb those around you. Stealth Audio Player enables you to make good use of the tiny speaker to listen things which should not play from the main big speaker.

Be aware that it hasn't as many options as VLC and other players.

> NOTE: This is not a full fledged music player.

***Disclaimer:*** I am not related to the app's developer(s).